# Navigation bar being hidden behind pics

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im trying to keep the Nav Menu allways on the front?
How can I make the Nav Menu be on top of all my content without hidding behind it?

My second question Is why the Nav Menu is "Flashing" somtimes when Im clicking On it?

js

```
$(function() {
    // Stick the #nav to the top of the window
    var nav = $('#nav');
    var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
    var isFixed = false;
    var $w = $(window);
    $w.scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
        var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
        if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
            nav.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 0,
                left: nav.offset().left,
                width: nav.width()
            });
            isFixed = true;
        }
        else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
        {
            nav.css({
                position: 'static'
            });
            isFixed = false;
        }
    });
});




$(document).ready(function() {

//set opacity to 0.4 for all the images
//opacity = 1 - completely opaque
//opacity = 0 - invisible

    $('.photos img').css('opacity', 0.4);

// when hover over the selected image change the opacity to 1
    $('.photos td').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('img').stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.4);
        });

});
```

css

```
.menu{

    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC';
    font-size: 30px;
```

html

```
<div id="nav" align="left">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<ul id="mymenu">
    <li class="menu"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#Dream">Dream</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="menu"><a href="#Love">Love</a></li>
</ul>
```

html of the problematic content

```
    <table class="photos" style="border-spacing: 0; border-width: 0; padding: 0 0; border-width: 0;  width: 100%;" >
    <tr>
        <td><img src="Dad.jpg" alt="Poppy" /></td>
        <td><img src="gili.jpg" alt="Poppy" /></td>
        <td><img src="me2.jpg" alt="Poppy" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <div> <td><img src="Hotrack.jpg" alt="Poppy" /></td>
            <td><img src="shir.jpg" alt="Poppy" /></td></div>

        <td><img src="" alt="Poppy" /></td>
        <td><img src="" alt="Poppy" /></td>
        <td><img src="" alt="Poppy" /></td>
        <td><img src="" alt="Poppy" /></td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a high z-index value to your navbar div like this:

```
#nav  {
   z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: It still the same :-\ and it also disrupts the background.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with your html, css and js please

Comment: Thank you, your first answer was correct I just forgot to close the brackets

Answer (score 0):

You can use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) property to keep nav on top of everything. Give the highest z-index to the nav

From the code you have provided I'm assuming the flashing you talked about is a text color change while clicking. To change this use this css

Disable color change while link is active(clicking)

```
a:active{
    color:blue;
}
```

Disable visited link color change

```
a:visited{
    color:blue;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qb76r93b/)

Answer (score 0):

As default `z-index:1;`. set any element `z-index:2` if you want it to the top of any other elements.

Example:

```
nav{ 
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2;
}
```